# Определение функций выделения и освобождения памяти

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Проходил недавно один тест, где наткнулся на такое задание:

Создайте функцию выделения памяти (`allocation_memory`) и освобождения (`free_memory`) для трехмерных массивов, используя следующие сигнатуры:

```
int ***allocation_memory(int first_dim, int second_dim, int third_dim);
void free_memory(int ***array, int first_dim, int second_dim);
```

Не могу придумать ничего толкового. Может есть у кого какие то соображения, поделитесь пожалуйста, буду благодарен.

Comment: Наверное, не трех, а трехмерных :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
int ***allocation_memory(int first_dim, int second_dim, int third_dim)
{
    int***F = new int**[first_dim];
    for(int i = 0; i < first_dim; ++i)
    {
        F[i] = new int*[second_dim];
        for(int j = 0; j < second_dim; ++j)
            F[i][j] = new int[third_dim];
    }
    return F;
}
```

Освобождение памяти сами напишете? а то иначе как-то неспортивно получается...